# Open embedded core: Adding packages to a build

Tags: linux, embed, openembedded

So using open embedded core and the Igepv2 meta layer I just finished building virtual/kernel, now if I want to add to this:

1. how would I go and add software packages to this, is it ok to change the bblayers/local.conf files then start a new recipe (would this just build upon what I have already got)?
2. What if I wanted to now build the angstrom distro, I saw that it requires a different set up to the oe-core layout is there a way to use what I got already here?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear.  You don't "add software packages" to virtual/kernel, you add software packages to an image recipe (core-image-base, for example.)  Building the virtual/kernel "target" only builds the kernel and any dependencies that are required to build the kernel.  You will ultimately want to build boot images, and there are several example image recipes to choose from, such as 'core-image-base' or core-image-sato', etc.  These build root file system images and usually bootloader images depending on the machine you are building.

It is definitely ok to modify bblayers.conf and/or local.conf.  Beware, though that anything you put in local.conf will basically be visible to every recipe bitbake processes.  bblayers.conf is the place where you would add your own layer(s) for customization, so the only thing you should be modifying in there is adding a layer directory to the stack.

You might want to check out 'hob', which is documented on the yoctoproject.org website.  This is a user interface that helps make it a bit easier to add packages to a recipe.  Plenty of documentation is available for all of this, though reading it will keep you busy for a couple days! :)

Also, feel free to post your questions on the yocto project mailing list, which is also detailed on the yoctoproject.org website.

Have fun!